# How to design database tables to describe somewhat restricted 1-to-1 relationship between 2 classes with specified third property

Tags: database

e.g. To describe the relationship between **Tutor** and **Student**, For any **Day**, a *tutor* can teach 0 or 1 *student*, and a *student* can take course of 0 or 1 tutor.

Following situations are illegal:

1. coexistence of relations (day1, tutor1, student1) and (day1, tutor2, student1), this means in day1, student1 both take courses of tutor1 and tutor2.
2. coexistence of relations (day1, tutor1, student1）and (day1, tutor1, student2）, this means in day1, tutor1 teach 2 students.

Following situations are legal:

1. coexistence of relations (day1, tutor1, student1）and (day2, tutor2, student1）
2. coexistence of relations (day1, tutor1, student1）and (day2, tutor1, student2）

So, how to design the tables?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a table (student, tutor, day) and also unique constraints on (student, day) and (tutor, day).

Comment: But which attributes can be then selected to combine the primary key? If weuse all these three attributes, dose it violate the 2NF?

Comment: The primary key could be either (student, day) or (tutor,day).